# How to pass a variable to two different view from a controller in Laravel

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-views, laravel-controller

I am working on developing a social networking site.

In my view folder there are two different folders:

1.layout:
Layout have app.blade file: This file contain an notification header like fb. example:
[Notification example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTp4W.png)

2.user : User have home.blade file: it is contain home view.

Now when any user logs in it goes to home view first,Home view fecthing data from home controller Like this :

```
return view('home',compact('data','postblog');
```

But I also want to show a notification in notification section of app.blade file. So, My question is how can I send the data to that view too along with home view?

If you know any other way of doing this, please guide me.

Comment: app.blade.php can access your data directly. don't need extra options

Comment: you means to say that compact('data') is accessible to app.blade? @RayCheng

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Comment: So, does it means that my all the variables in compact () in all view of user folder is accessible directly of app.blade?

Comment: app.blade.php is a layout, your blade must extend from the layout.

Comment: Ok. thats the reason. Now I am understanding that, if i Extent a layout then whatever the data I am accessing from controller in any user folder view blade file, that will be available to that extent()  of layout in other view.Am I right? @RayCheng

Comment: yes. that is true, read the doc or do your own tests

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.blade.php can access your data directly. don't need extra options as mentioned above by Ray Cheng.

Or you can do that using view composer method For more : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views